# How do I reset my Unity configuration on 15.10?

Tags: unity, gnome, 15.04, compiz, 15.10

I know that there are similar questions regarding what I'm about to ask, but I have tried several suggestions in an attempt to fix my problem, to no avail. My desktop background is blank and I need to know how to reset my Unity configuration. I was trying to load Gnome and I accidentally deleted (or disabled might be a better word) my Unity Desktop Environment, which created a login loop. I believe this happened when i typed:

```
sudo apt-get remove gnome-desktop3-data
```

I am very green to Linux and had used a deprecated command to install Gnome:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-desktop
```

So, I attempted to remove (and possibly `purge`) gnome-desktop based on another post, but I used tab-completion and that's how I deleted gnome-desktop3-data.

I may have deleted some other dependencies along the way because after I rebooted I had a login loop. I used <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and installed ubuntu-gnome-desktop to make things a little easier (because I suck and needed a GUI), but had no luck with getting Unity back. I tried `sudo apt-get update` , `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` and `sudo apt-get install unity`. I also tried `dconf reset -f /org/compiz/` and received this output:

> (ccsm:2739): GLib-GIO-WARNING **: g_settings_set_value: value for key 'visual-bell-type' in schema 'org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences' is outside of valid range

When I type `setsid unity`, I don't have a background and more g_settings_set_value. . . output followed by:

> WARN  2015-11-29 15:53:20 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:593 Can't register object 'org.gnome.Shell' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
>
> WARN  2015-11-29 15:53:20 unity.debug.interface DebugDBusInterface.cpp:217 Unable to load entry point in libxpathselect: libxpathselect.so.1.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory -- full D-Bus introspection will not be available
>
> WARN  2015-11-29 15:53:20 unity.dash.gsettingsscopereader GSettingsScopes.cpp:108 Error fetching protocol metadata for scope: social.scope : Valid key file could not be found in search dirs
>
> WARN  2015-11-29 15:53:20 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:593 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Launcher' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
>
> WARN  2015-11-29 15:53:20 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:593 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Dash' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
>
> WARN  2015-11-29 15:53:21 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:593 Can't register object 'org.gnome.SessionManager.EndSessionDialog' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
>
> WARN  2015-11-29 15:53:21 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:593 Can't register object 'com.canonical.Unity.Session' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
>
> WARN  2015-11-29 15:53:21 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:593 Can't register object 'org.gnome.ScreenSaver' yet as we don't have a connection, waiting for it...
>
> ERROR 2015-11-29 15:53:21 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:538 DBus name lost 'org.gnome.Shell'
>
> ERROR 2015-11-29 15:53:21 unity.glib.dbus.server GLibDBusServer.cpp:538 DBus name lost 'com.canonical.Unity'
>
> WARN  2015-11-29 15:53:21 unity.key.gnome.grabber GnomeKeyGrabber.cpp:99 Trying to grab a disabled action, we skip it. . .
>
> mickyhale@ubuntu:~$ ERROR 2015-11-29 15:53:31 unityfree :0 g_variant_get_type: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
>
> ERROR 2015-11-29 15:53:31 unityfree :0 g_variant_type_is_subtype_of: assertion 'g_variant_type_check (type)' failed
>
> ERROR 2015-11-29 15:53:31 unity.filemanager.gnome GnomeFileManager.cpp:60 Locations value type is not matching the expected one!

I also tried:

```
DISPLAY=:0 gsettings reset org.compiz.core:/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/core/ active-plugins
```

and then:

```
DISPLAY=:0 ccsm&
```

But, I cannot select Ubuntu Unity Plugin without disabling Window Decoration and Gnome Compatibility.

I am truly sorry for the long-winded explanation of what I have tried and admit that I probably shouldn't be messing with things I don't have a comprehensive understanding about, but I am trying to learn and would appreciate any guidance. I was using 15.04 and then upgraded to 15.10 in an attempt to fix a possible dependency? issue I may have created. This did not help.

Answer (score 1):

**To reset the the configuration run this:**

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

**Try a full reinstall, open terminal and run these commands one at a time**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install unity
```